# Run make once and distribute?

Tags: centos

I was just curious if I run make on development machine if the make produces an "install" of some type that I can copy to other machines? So that I could just run make install on the other machines after copying the "install"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to [build a package](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Docs/Drafts/BuildingPackagesGuide) that you can then deploy to your other machines using yum.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the package.  make and autotools are Turing-complete and have full access to the system, so they could be doing literally anything during the build.  If you copy from one system to a nearly-identical one, you'll probably be okay -- but short of reviewing Makefile.am/configure.ac/etcetera in their entirety, there's no way to be sure.